# purpose of creating thumbs

Tags: php, image, gd

I want to know the purpose of creating thumbs dynamically? If we have the option in `<img>` tag to set height and width of the image?
I just want to know which one is a good practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the height and width attributes of the `<img>` tag only control the size of the image rendered on a page. If you try to use size and width for  a thumbnail for  a 4 MB image file, it will still load the 4 MB image. Now if you do that for a whole image gallery, you'll be waiting some time for the page to load. If you use thumbnail images, which are scaled down images based on your original 4 MB image, the page will probably load much faster since the thumbnails will probably only be in the 100's of KB or less.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically changing the dimensions of the image reduces the amount of data needed to be transferred to the client, thus reducing server traffic and loading time.

Answer (score 0):

this is because the user viewing your webpage don't want wait a long time for loading your `scaled` `big size` images.

Answer (score 0):

So that you don't have to download a gigantic picture when you only want to see a small one